# kwin: key binding to move a client to a different desktop

Tags: x11, kde, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop, kwin

*How does one go about adding a Kwin shortcut that reassigns a client to a
different desktop?*

KDE is set up for nine desktops with keyboard shortcuts for Kwin for navigating
between them using `META+{1..9}`. Now I have misplaced a client on the wrong
desktop: Instead of 2 I need it to be accessible under 3. (Using the titlebar
buttons (there is one for “display on all desktops” IIRC) is not an option as
titlebars are eliminated globally.) The settings menu (entry “Desktop Behavior > 
Virtual Desktops”) doesn’t offer mappings for this kind of action.

Optimally, such a mapping would conform to the `SHIFT+META+{1..9}` convention
that is the default with most window managers, though I’d be content with a
less convenient shortcut.

The question pertains specifically to KDE 5/Kwin 5.4.3 on Fedora 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in KDE4 but I believe you'll find it in the KDE5 too (System Settings, something about shortcuts):
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that’s exactly what I was looking for! Although now I have the problem that it won’t let me bind this to ``META+SHIFT-{1..9}`` -- it appears to treat ``SHIFT-{1..9}`` the same as the unmodified number. Why on earth would it do that?

Comment: So I researched the matter a bit and it would appear that v5 of KDE at this point is incapable of assigning ``SHIFT`` as a modifier in this constellation. This is a [known bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=341959) and people appear to defend it by citing backward compatibility. I think I’ve reached a point where getting rid of KDE entirely has much lower opportunity cost than constantly working around its issues.